# Adapted to the windows compiler, I feel pathetic. What is the problem

Tags: arrays, c

I am in C language
Arrays were implemented using input and output functions.
The code is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n;   
   int arr[1000];

   printf("Enter the number of numbers to enter : \n"); 
   scanf("%d", &n);

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {   
      scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
   }

   for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      printf("&d ", arr[i]);
   }
return 0;
}
```

However, after running the compilation, this resulted. Below is the (vscode, gcc) console window.

```
Enter the number of numbers to enter : 
5
1 2 3 4 5
&d &d &d &d &d
```

I don't understand why the notation like %d %d %d appears here.
Adapted to the windows compiler, I feel pathetic. What is the problem

Comment: You used `&d`, you meant `%d` (just like in `scanf`). The `&d` just prints those literal characters, `%d` is a placeholder for the value passed to be formatted/printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line ie causing the issue:

```
printf("&d ", arr[i]);
```

You are printing not scanning for inputs, it should be like this:

```
printf("%d ", arr[i]);
```